# Managing Permissions Issue after SharePoint 2007 to 2013 Migration

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am really struggling with this and any input would be appreciated.

After SharePoint Migration (with the Database Attach method) from 2007->2010->2013 multiple **subsites** in a **sitecollection** are having Problems.

Managing Permissions from Site Settings is not possible:

/domain/sitecollection/subsiteA/_layouts/15/people.aspx
/domain/sitecollection/subsiteA/_layouts/15/user.aspx

The Two Pages are Throwing an Error

```
An unexpected error has occurred:
Log:
Application error when access /_layouts/15/people.aspx, Error=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.  Parameter name: index   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ListSiteMapPath.CreateControlHierarchy()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapPath.CreateChildControls()     at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeControl.get_Controls()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlByWalkingInner(Control rootControl, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlByWalkingInner(Control rootControl, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlByWalkingInner(Control rootControl, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlB... a042ca9d-e5a1-3092-22c7-5be152697ad2
...yWalkingInner(Control rootControl, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlByWalkingInner(Control rootControl, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlByWalkingInner(Control rootControl, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlByWalkingInner(Control rootControl, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlByWalking(Control namingContainer, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.set_TemplateId(String value)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.InitializeControlIds(Control namingContainerScope)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.OnLoad(EventArgs eventArgs)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at Sys...  a042ca9d-e5a1-3092-22c7-5be152697ad2
...tem.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)   a042ca9d-e5a1-3092-22c7-5be152697ad2
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.  Parameter name: index    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ListSiteMapPath.CreateControlHierarchy()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapPath.CreateChildControls()     at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeControl.get_Controls()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlByWalkingInner(Control rootControl, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlByWalkingInner(Control rootControl, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlByWalkingInner(Control rootControl, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlByWalkingInner(Control roo... a042ca9d-e5a1-3092-22c7-5be152697ad2
...tControl, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlByWalkingInner(Control rootControl, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlByWalkingInner(Control rootControl, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlByWalkingInner(Control rootControl, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlByWalking(Control namingContainer, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.set_TemplateId(String value)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.InitializeControlIds(Control namingContainerScope)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.OnLoad(EventArgs eventArgs)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRe...  a042ca9d-e5a1-3092-22c7-5be152697ad2
...cursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    a042ca9d-e5a1-3092-22c7-5be152697ad2
Getting Error Message for Exception System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.  Parameter name: index     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ListSiteMapPath.CreateControlHierarchy()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapPath.CreateChildControls()     at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeControl.get_Controls()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlByWalkingInner(Control rootControl, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlByWalkingInner(Control rootControl, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlByWalkingInner(Control rootControl, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.... a042ca9d-e5a1-3092-22c7-5be152697ad2
...FindControlByWalkingInner(Control rootControl, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlByWalkingInner(Control rootControl, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlByWalkingInner(Control rootControl, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlByWalkingInner(Control rootControl, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.FindControlByWalking(Control namingContainer, String id)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.set_TemplateId(String value)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.InitializeControlIds(Control namingContainerScope)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu.OnLoad(EventArgs eventArgs)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive(...  a042ca9d-e5a1-3092-22c7-5be152697ad2
...)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)   a042ca9d-e5a1-3092-22c7-5be152697ad2
```

What I've figured out so far:

1. Groups are there:
    -/domain/sitecollection/subsiteA/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=3898 throws the same Error.
   -/domain/sitecollection/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=3898 but direct in sitecollection the group is found
2. Subsites where permissions are working:
   /domain/sitecollection/subsiteB/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=6618 is displayed correctly,
   but when I change the list view from the Default Detail View to another View, the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the Problem and it was not caused by the Migration, it was caused by a Custom Control (Implemented for the BreadCrumb Navigation).

The Control was Implemented from the Example on the [Link](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2015/08/sharepoint-2013-breadcrumb/), 
SiteMapProviders="SPSiteMapProvider,**SPXmlContentMapProvider**"

The **SPXmlContentMapProvider** did cause an exception but not always, **just when a SiteCollection had a White Space in the URL**, and only if you have navigated to the Permission Managing Page.